# Filtering an item from a list

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this:

```
<type 'list'>
[('crap', 0), ('jou', 0), ('gaat', 0), ('awesome', 0), ('awesome?', 0),  ('met', 0), ('nou', 0), ('useless', 0), ('bananen', -1.4447848426728962), ('appels', -1.8073549220576042)]
```

What I would like to do now is filter the 'bananen' value -> -1.44

However, if I do:

```
item = [elem for elem in top_neg if elem[1] == 'bananen']
print(item)
```

This gives me an empty item. Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: Indexing is zero-based. You need to check `elem[0]`.

Comment: It looks like you shoud be using a dictionary. You wouldn't have to roll your own lookup.

Answer (score 0):

```
print([elem for elem in top_neg if elem[0] == 'bananen'])
```

you're testing the wrong element

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to convert the list to a dictionary, the benefits for a dictionary include:

1. You can check if the key exists or not;
2. The time complexity for dictionary in Python is mostly O(1), so it will be very quick if you have a large dataset.

See an example:

```
sample_list = [('crap', 0), ('jou', 0), ('gaat', 0), ('awesome', 0), ('awesome?', 0),  ('met', 0), ('nou', 0), ('useless', 0), ('bananen', -1.4447848426728962), ('appels', -1.8073549220576042)]

sample_dic = dict(sample_list)

sample_dic.get('bananen', -99) 
# -1.4447848426728962

sample_dic.get('banaeeeeeeeee',-99)
# -99

sample_dic.get('appels', -99)
# -1.8073549220576042
```